# Get more info from Scheduled Tasks in powershell

Tags: windows, powershell, scheduled-tasks

Is there a way to view all ScheduledTask properties from PowerShell without having to open up the not so user friendly taskschd.msc:

I manage to create the job fine with `New-ScheduledTask` and `Register-ScheduledTask`, but I'm unable to view the parameters like Action, Trigger, Principal and Settings, that I used in `New-ScheduledTask`

Below is what I manage to get:

```
Get-ScheduledTask -TaskName "test22 BAM-AT" -Verbose

TaskPath                                       TaskName                          State
--------                                       --------                          -----
\                                              test22 BAM-AT                     Ready


Get-ScheduledTaskInfo -TaskName "test22 BAM-AT" -Verbose


LastRunTime        : 2/23/2021 1:44:44 PM
LastTaskResult     : 0
NextRunTime        : 2/23/2021 4:00:00 PM
NumberOfMissedRuns : 0
TaskName           : test22 BAM-AT
TaskPath           :
PSComputerName     :
```

Comment: `Get-ScheduledTask -TaskName "test22 BAM-AT" -Verbose | Select *` will show all properties including Actions, Triggers, Principal & Settings. You can view these properties by using `(Get-ScheduledTask -TaskName "test22 BAM-AT" -Verbose | Select *).actions` changing `.actions` with the required property.

Comment: Thanks using ' ... | select -ExpandProperty Actions' expands the Action

Comment: Above comments should be in the answer.  They worked great, and clarified something that was very confusing.

Answer (score 2):

The Cim base ScheduledTasks module doesn't expose that level of detail up front. However, you can use another of it's cmdlets `Export-ScheduledTask` to get the XML task definition and parse it like an object.

Example:

```
$TaskXML = [XML]((Get-ScheduledTask)[0] |Export-ScheduledTask)
$TaskXML.Task.Triggers
```

Obviously you may have to poke around to extract the information you want etc...

`Export-ScheduledTask` returns all the XML you would need to import the task on another system, so it should have all the details, it's just a matter of extracting the XML.

**Update Addressing Comments:**

I apparently didn't realize there's more information returned and accessible from `Get-ScheduledTask`.  However, `Select-Object` (`select *` above) isn't needed to access that information.  Doing so will dehydrate the returned object, which may affect secondary use of it.  The objects returned after Select are `[PSCustomObjects]` as opposed to a typical `[CimInstance]`.

Thanks to @CraftyB's comments, here are some examples without the unnecessary `Select-Object`:

```
(ScheduledTask -TaskName "test22 BAM-AT").Actions
```

OR:

```
(ScheduledTask -TaskName "test22 BAM-AT").Triggers
```

Reference properties as needed.

Without more work, it is unclear to me if there are advantages or disadvantages to exporting the XML versus just referencing the properties. It's possible information is available in one approach that isn't in another.

Answer (score 0):

If you get a list of all the taskNames you're interested in, then Get the Property set for one, you can get more info than you want:

```
$names = Get-ScheduledTask -TaskPath \ | select -exp TaskName

$TaskProps = Get-ScheduledTask -TaskName $names[0] | gm | ? { $_.memberType -EQ "Property" | select -exp Name}

foreach ($name in $names) {
    write $name
    $TaskProps | % { (get-ScheduledTask -TaskName $name).$_ }
}
```